# JQuery treating my non-empty array as empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Very simply I have built a multi-dimensional array across a long section of script and at the end I want to loop through each level and do something. I have logged the array out in the console and can see everything as it should be, but the console then tells me the array length is 0 and sure enough if I `.length` it is also tells me the length is 0, so my JQuery each isn't firing. I can't understand what one can do to make it behave like this. I am absolutely stumped!

This is the console:
[image]

Here is the JQuery, although the array/object is built over so much script and ajax calls that I've tried to only put in the bits that count...

```
var field_layers = [];

function blah_blah() {
    do_api_call("api_call_url_here")
        .done(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            var map_layers = response;
            $(map_layers).each(function(map_layers_key, map_layers_detail) {
                var datalayer_id = map_layers_detail.Layer.DataLayerId;

                // add field ids to array:
                field_layers["field_id_"+map_layers_detail.Layer.FieldId] = [];
                do_api_call("api_call_url_here/"+datalayer_id)
                    .done(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                        // create an empty array for field layers:
                        field_layers["field_id_"+map_layers_detail.Layer.FieldId]["layer_id_"+datalayer_id] = [];
                        var map_layer_zones = response;
                        $(map_layer_zones).each(function(map_layer_zone_key, map_layer_zone_detail) {
                            // Add the zones to the layer
                            field_layers["field_id_"+map_layers_detail.Layer.FieldId]["layer_id_"+datalayer_id].push({
                                "zone_id":zone.DataLayerZoneId,
                                "title":zone.DataLayerZoneId+" title here"
                            });
                        });
                    });
            });
        });
}

function go_to_field(field_id) { // this is what gives me the console screenshot
    console.log("field_id: "+field_id);
    console.log(field_layers["field_id_"+field_id]);
    console.log(field_layers["field_id_"+field_id].length);
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant jquery.

Comment: You appear to be using an array as if it were an object, and then expecting it to still act like an array. This likely has absolutely nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: @TylerRoper I will but it's so long and drawn out I didn't think it would be helpful, considering it logs out in the console fine. Give me a minute.

Comment: Weird, it works here https://jsfiddle.net/L4qren2n/

Comment: @KevinB shouldn't Jquery each work with both though?

Comment: eh, it actually looks like you have an array-like object, that still somehow has a length property set to 0. Yes, jquery can work with array-like objects, but that has nothing to do with what you're seeing in your console. An array or array-like object with two items and a length of 0 is not normal.

Comment: @KevinB no I know... I just don't know how I've done it and everything I try doesn't seem to make a difference. I've updated the code with the Jquery I used to build it now. Hope you can understand it!

Comment: @TylerRoper have updated ith JQuery now. Hope you can understand it!

Comment: field_layers is an array, why are you giving it keys like an object?

Comment: You should not be doing **var field_layers = []**; and **field_layers ["layer_id_1"] = [];** and expecting array itteration

Comment: I come from PHP and really struggle with this. Obviously in hindsight I need an object but it didn't error and logged out fine so I thought it was ok. Could someone explain how to achieve this with objects please? And be gentle guys!

Comment: And what's with the downvotes?! I came here because I was stuck... I've spent all evening trying to sort it out, googling and banging my head against a brick wall, and I didn't post my JQuery because in reality it's about 250 lines longer than what I've put up there with a tonne of AJAX calls that I thought would confuse the issue. Where's the love?! Creating Objects to act as associative arrays really confuses me.. I can create them, as I have done for the `// Add the zones to the layer` bit of my code but I don't know how to add more than one to the same key... that's all I'm asking.

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns I'm really confused about the downvotes, too... This was a solidly worded question for a legitimate question about the difference between arrays in PHP and Javascript. You used StackOverflow correctly and I hate that your question is getting this type of negative attention. Don't give up on SO, though!

Comment: @daniel0mullins thanks for the solidarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `field_layers = []` to be an object instead of an array: `field_layers = {}`. I think if you change each place you are initializing an empty array to initializing an empty object, then your code should work as-is.

Notice the difference between square brackets and curly braces.

With you coming from a PHP background, you can think of Javascript objects (the `{}`) as associative (or named) arrays in PHP.

So the final code would look like:

```
var field_layers = {};

function blah_blah() {
    do_api_call("api_call_url_here")
        .done(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
            var map_layers = response;
            $(map_layers).each(function(map_layers_key, map_layers_detail) {
                var datalayer_id = map_layers_detail.Layer.DataLayerId;

                // add field ids to object:
                field_layers["field_id_"+map_layers_detail.Layer.FieldId] = {};
                do_api_call("api_call_url_here/"+datalayer_id)
                    .done(function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                    var map_layer_zones = response;
                    $(map_layer_zones).each(function(map_layer_zone_key, map_layer_zone_detail) {
                        // Add the zones to the layer
                        field_layers["field_id_"+map_layers_detail.Layer.FieldId]["layer_id_"+datalayer_id] = {
                            "zone_id":zone.DataLayerZoneId,
                            "title":zone.DataLayerZoneId+" title here"
                        }; // notice the assignment of object literal here
                    });
                });
        });
    });
}

function go_to_field(field_id) { // this is what gives me the console screenshot
    console.log("field_id: "+field_id);
    console.log(field_layers["field_id_"+field_id]);
    console.log(field_layers["field_id_"+field_id].length);
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much... can't believe it was that simple!

Comment: Glad to help! You found an interesting way to break Javascript that I hadn't seen before! Arrays were behaving more like generic collections that didn't have a size. You should check out 'Javascript: The Good Parts' by Douglas Crockford for the end-all primer on Javascript.

Comment: I shall. Thanks for the tip!